# MapView shows pin location and then disappears

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

I've never used the Map-view before, and I was following [this](http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/) tutorial

At the very end, my simulator shows the point the way it is supposed to, in the location it is supposed to, but then immediately changes to a blue screen.

the blue screen is still in Google maps (It shows the Google logo at the bottom) but it is no longer what I am trying to show.

[image: First it looks like this]
[image: After a moment it looks like this]

Here is some of my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    HandbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HandbookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Rule *thisRule = [delegate.rules objectAtIndex:index.row];

    self.title = thisRule.ruleNumber;

    // Set some coordinates for our position (Buckingham Palace!)
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = (double) 51.501468;
    location.longitude = (double) -0.141596;

    // Add the annotation to our map view
    MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buckingham Palace" andCoordinate:location];
    [self.map addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    [newAnnotation release];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to discover the solution on my own. Turns out it was rather silly.

I had turned on "shows user location" on the xib for my MKMapView, so that was interfering. When I turned it off, the problem went away.